# Swift multiple TabBarControllers in one application

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm pretty new to iOS development, and while making my first app, I couldn't figure out how to implement different TabBars for different Views. I have a TableView inside a NavigationController, inside a TabBarController. The TabBar for NavigationViewController has "Home" and "Settings".

When the user clicks on a TableView Cell, DetailViewController shows, and I really wanted to make it so that in the DetailViewController, there would be a different TabBar as the "Invite" button. Something like how in the Reddit application, the TabBar seemingly changes depending on whether you've clicked on the post or not (refer to screenshots).

[TabBar at Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfxse.png) [TabBar inside post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib5M2.png)

I tried embedding a separate TabBarController for the DetailView, but it didn't work( maybe I didn't do it correctly). I'm probably asking the wrong question since I'm not getting anything from Google. I'm especially unfamiliar with TabBarControllers, so I'd very much like to learn about how this implementation is done. I am absolutely clueless; any sort of help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Tabbar controllers in a storyboard.
Create a UITabBarController class for each tab bar.
Add a Navigation Controller.
Push from Tabbar1 to Tabbar 2 like viewController

```
@IBAction func btnCheckClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar2") as? TabBar2
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! This works great however, in my case I use two Navigation Bar Button items, and one of it is an "Add" button to add a new cell in my TableView. When I use this method, it makes it so that I can only add BarButtonItems inside TabBar1, the TabBarController. That would mean that I have to implement adding a new element to the TableView inside TabBar1 class, and I do not know how I would achieve this.

Comment: you can create a function of adding a button on navigation bar ... and calls it on 2nd tabBar to get the same button ... as your tabBar is changed

Comment: and if you have many Navigation controllers and want rightBarButton on Each one of them. then you can Add it to app delegate by using UINavigationItem

Comment: also, an upvote will be appreciated